# Technical Documentation for Developers

Tags: documentation, system-requirements

I have a users and permissions matrix diagram and an interaction diagram that shows which type of user role can edit/add which user role (for example, an Admin can grant access for all the users in the system, a "Normal User" can't grant roles/access to any user).

The requirement is: "Develop all needed software documentation for developers. This is an output used by developers to start working on the features". This is given in the context where we have an web app and the developers need to start working on this user/permissions roles and understand how the functionalities are tied together for each type of user.

My question is, how can I do something like this? What kind of documentation, information is needed and are there any examples, anywhere? I did business requirements documents before, but not so technical and usually this is done together with an IT lead, but given this is a test I need to create some content on my own with my own assumptions.

Thanks!